# The problem complexity of the Maximum Coverage problem with set size constraint (P or NP)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np

The classic Maximum Coverage (MC) problem is an NP-hard optimization problem. Consider d elements **U = {e1, e2, ... ed}** and c sets **T1, T2 ... Tc**. Each set contains some elements in U. The problem aims to find at most **b** sets, such that the cardinality of the union of these sets is maximized. 
For example, T1={e1, e3}, T2={e1, e2, e3} and T3={e3, e4}. When b=2, the optimal solution picks T2 and T3. 
I am considering a variation of the classic MC problem, which imposes a set size constraint. Consider 1 < k <= d, if the size of all sets is bounded by k. Call this problem **k-MC**. Is the problem still NP-hard?

My conjecture is that **k-MC** is still NP-hard, but I am struggling to come up with a polynomial reduction from a proven NP-hard problem, like MC. 
For an arbitrary instance of Maximum coverage, if I could find a polynomial reduction to my problem for all k>1, I can conclude that my problem is also NP-hard. 
Here is what I got so far:

1. When k=d, the problem is trivially equivalent to the classic Maximum Coverage.
2. When k=d-1, we look at the given MC instance and see if there exist a set with size d. If there is, simply pick that. Otherwise, it reduces to the **k-MC** problem with k=d-1.

When k is less than d-1, I resort to dynamic programming to complete the reduction. However, this yields a non-polynomial time reduction, which defeat the purpose of reduction from a NP-hard problem.

If anyone could give me some pointers on how I should tackle this problem, or even just make an educated guess on the problem complexity of **k-MC** (P or NP), I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the theory of computing, not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 2):

2-MC is easy -- interpret the sets of size 2 as a graph and run your favorite matching algorithm for non-bipartite graphs. Once you exceed the matching cardinality, you're stuck picking singletons.

3-MC is hard. You can encode an instance of [3-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) as 3-MC by taking the sets to be the triples that sum to the target, then decide if it's solvable by checking coverage for b = n/3.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. In the case of k>=3, can I always use a reduction from k-partition problem and prove k-MC is in NP? I suppose 4-partition and 5-partition are also NP-hard like 3-MC.

Comment: @bipartite_master Yes.